# How to compare the corresponding items of two arrays in a one-liner?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Say I have two arrays of the same length. E.g.:

```
Dim a() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim b() As Integer = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
```

Now I want to check if **all** items in `b` are greater than the corresponding items (same index) in `a` :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
    If b(i) <= a(i)
        Return False
    End If
Next
Return True
```

Is there a one-line solution for that? Maybe something using LINQ's All() method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289566/how-to-join-two-collections-by-index-in-linq

Comment: `For i As Int32 = 0 To a.Length - 1 : If b(i) <= a(i) : Return False : End If : Next : Return True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you:

```
Dim result As Boolean = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).All(Function(i As Integer) b(i) > a(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the arrays are of different size

```
    Dim result As Boolean = a.Length = b.Length AndAlso Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).All(Function(i As Integer) b(i) > a(i))
```