# How to merge two lists so that indexes remain the same?

Tags: c#, list, merge

I have two lists, one for `names`, one for `values`.
I need to *merge* them together so that *first* name in the list merges with *first* value from the other list.
In other words, name and value need to have the same index in the same list.

I tried `Concat()` method, but it just expands the list by adding values to the end.

Comment: Please show us what you tried, along with a decent input sample (in this case 2 lists) + what your code produced + what you wanted to get instead

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Two different objects cannot have the same index in a list, that doesn't make any sense. Are you perhaps thinking about a list of (key, value) pairs? Or maybe even dictionaries?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to exactly how the two lists will be merged, but perhaps this is a duplicate of [How to concatenate two collections by index in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2289566/3744182), to which the answer is, use `Enumerable.Zip()`.  Agree?

Comment: It seems clear to me. I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you are looking for [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0), not `Concat`:

```
List<string> names = ...
List<int> values = ...

var result = names
  .Zip(values, (name, value) => (name, value))
  .ToList(); // let's materialize result as a list
```